# Cannot install npm packages from Sonatype Nexus private repository

Tags: node.js, sonatype, nexus3

I am using Sonatype nexus as my repository where I have configured npm to have public and private repositories.

- npm-public -> proxy for npm registry.
- npm-private -> private repository to publish company related repositories.
- npm-group -> group having access to above two repositories.

my .npmrc file has config

```
registry=<<private_repo_url>>/npm-group/
_auth=<<token>>
strict-ssl=false
always-auth=true
```

I get the following error when I install my private package on my local machine

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Although I can publish my private packages to <<private_repo_url>>/npm-internal/

I am on `windows` laptop using `git bash`.
Sonatype Nexus version: `3.15.2`
nodejs: `v12.21.0`
npm: `6.14.11`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure that  your token is correct , your .npmrc file is in the correct location by using npm config ls -l  , and npm Bearer Token Realm is active in your nexus configuration realms

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `npm Bearer Token Realm` to your security configuration

[image]

Comment: I was trying to publish my package (I'm new with Nexus) and this resolved my problem. Thanks!